# Identify Wallet based upon word phrase

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have my 12 words and used Trust wallet to import my (unidentified) wallet but I'm not sure of which wallet site it comes from.

Is there anyway to identify which wallet it is by my 12 words in using the Trust wallet app or by any other method?

Thank you,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

We can rule out  Bitcoin-core since no version of that, to date, has any support for mnemonic phrases.

If the words come from the [old Electrum wordlist](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/3.2.2/lib/old_mnemonic.py#L30) or [new Electrum wordlist](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spesmilo/electrum/master/electrum/wordlist/english.txt) the phrase was probably generated by Electrum.

If all twelve words come from the [BIP39 word list](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) they could have been generated by any of the [wallets that support BIP-39](https://www.blockplate.com/blogs/blockplate/list-of-bip39-wallets-mnemonic-seed). So there is no way to tell which wallet was used.